# In Sitecore powershell, can you make an item unpublishable

Tags: powershell, sitecore

In Sitecore Powershell for Sitecore 7.2...

Is it possible to set the "Publishable" rights on given items (to make them unpublishable)?

Specifically, I wish to automate the process of: selecting an item, opening `Publish > Restrictions > Change`, clicking the Item tab, and unchecking the "Publishable" box.

I've tried find that property of an item with no luck. I thought this might work, but "__Publishable" is not correct:

```
(get-item -Path master:/sitecore/content/Path/Home/About-Us)."__Publishable"
```

Is there a way to make Powershell report ALL of the properties of an item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The field for making an item un-publishable is:

`__Never publish`

So you could do this:

```
(get-item -Path master:/sitecore/content/DIAGlobal/Home/About-Us)."__Never publish"
```

Or if you wanted to edit it similar to back end code you could do:

```
$item = Get-Item master:/sitecore/content/DIAGlobal/Home/About-Us
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item["__Never publish"] = "1"
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

Some good examples of how to read and edit fields with Powershell can be found here: http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2014/10/12/working-with-sitecore-items-in-powershell-extensions/

Comment: Thanks, that's a great tip. I would add that the place to find all the properties is on the template item, in the "Inheritance" tab. The "__Hide version" property is also great for making specific things publishable/ununpublishable.

Answer (score 0):

I have next script

```
    function GetItemDatasources {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Item]$Item)
  
    # grab all datasources that are not header and footer elements
    return Get-Rendering -Item $item -FinalLayout -Device (Get-LayoutDevice -Default) |
        Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Datasource)} |
        Where-Object { $_.Placeholder -ne 'Above Page Content' } |
        Where-Object { $_.Placeholder -ne 'Below Page Content' } |
        ForEach-Object { Get-Item "$($item.Database):" -ID $_.Datasource }
        # ForEach-Object { Write-Host ($_ | Format-List | Out-String) }
}
  
$location = get-location
  
$languages = Get-ChildItem "master:\sitecore\system\Languages"
$currentLanguage = [Sitecore.Context]::Language.Name
  
$langOptions = @{};
  
$actions = @{};
$actions["Unpublish"] = "1";
$actions["Publish"] = "";
  
foreach ($lang in $languages) {
    $langOptions[$lang.Name] = $lang.Name
}
  
$result = Read-Variable -Parameters `
    @{ Name = "destinationLanguages"; Title="Language(s) for publich/unpublish"; Options=$langOptions; Editor="checklist"; },
    @{ Name = "includeSubitems"; Value=$false; Title="Include Subitems"; Columns = 4;},
    @{ Name = "action"; Value="1"; Title="Action"; Options=$actions; Tooltip="Unpublish: Set language as unblishded on all langauge vestions.<br>Publish: Set language as publishded on all langauge vestions."; }`
    -Description "Select languages that should be proceed during updates" `
    -Title "Language Publish - Unpublish" -Width 650 -Height 660 -OkButtonName "Proceed" -CancelButtonName "Cancel" -ShowHints
  
if($result -ne "ok") {
    Exit
}
  
Write-Host "destinationLanguages = $destinationLanguages"
  
$items = @()
  
$items += Get-Item $location
  
# add optional subitems
if ($includeSubitems) {
    $items += Get-ChildItem $location -Recurse
}
  
# Remove any duplicates, based on ID
$items = $items | Sort-Object -Property 'ID' -Unique
  
$items | ForEach-Object { Write-Host ($_.ItemPath | Sort-Object | Format-List | Out-String) }
  
$message = "You are about to publish/unpublish <span style='font-weight: bold'>$($items.Count) item(s)</span> with the following options:<br>"
$message += "<br><table>"
$message += "<tr><td style='width: auto'>Languages:</td><td>$destinationLanguages</td></tr>"
$message += "<tr><td style='width: auto'>Include Subitems:</td><td>$includeSubitems</td></tr>"
$message += "</table>"
$message += "<br><p style='font-weight: bold'>Are you sure?</p>"
  
$proceed = Show-Confirm -Title $message
  
if ($proceed -ne 'yes') {
    Write-Host "Canceling"
    Exit
}
  
Write-Host "Proceeding with execution"
  
$items | ForEach-Object { 
    $vitems = Get-Item $_.ID -Language $destinationLanguages -Version *
    $vitems | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Editing.BeginEdit()
        $_["__Hide version"] = $action
        $_.Editing.EndEdit()
    }
}
```